# Should I use will/didSetValueForKey inside a custom setter?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios6, key-value-observing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Receiving 2 KVO notifications for a single KVC change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4451861/receiving-2-kvo-notifications-for-a-single-kvc-change)

I'm confused about where I should be using [`willChangeValueForKey:` and `didChangeValueForKey:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueObserving_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

I have an object with a property which requires a custom setter method. As per [the Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOCompliance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002178-BAJEAIEE), I am using `will/didChangeValueForKey:`:

> To implement manual observer notification, you invoke willChangeValueForKey: before changing the value, and didChangeValueForKey: after changing the value. The example in Listing 3 implements manual notifications for the openingBalance property.
>
> **Listing 3**  Example accessor method implementing manual notification
>
> ```
> - (void)setOpeningBalance:(double)theBalance {
>     [self willChangeValueForKey:@"openingBalance"];
>     _openingBalance = theBalance;
>     [self didChangeValueForKey:@"openingBalance"];
> }
> ```

This makes my object look something like the below:

```
@interface cObject
@property (readwrite, nonatomic) BOOL Property;
@end

@implementation cObject
- (void)setProperty:(BOOL)Property
{
   [self willChangeValueForKey:@"Property"];
   _Property = Property;
   [self didChangeValueForKey:@"Property"];
   //Do some other stuff
}
@end
```

The source of my confusion is that if I set up another object to observe `Property` on an instance of `cObject` and then call `[myObject setProperty:]`, my observer's callback function is hit **twice**. Looking at the stack: the first hit happens as a result of me calling `didChangeValueForKey:`, the second hit is a direct result of me calling `setProperty:` (i.e. my custom setter does not appear in the stack).

To further add to the confusion, if I change `_Property` in another function elsewhere in `cObject`, my observer will **not** be notified (unless I use `did/willChangeValueForKey:`, of course!).

**EDIT:** Even if I do not change `_Property` in my custom setter, KVO notifies my observer that it has changed. From this, I conclude that KVO is being invoked as just a result of me calling the setter, regardless of whether anything changes or not...

Can anybody explain how my situation differs from that explained in the documentation?

Comment: are you sure it's hit twice for the same object? perhaps multiple observers of a single object? or a single observer registered twice?

Comment: @FernandoMazzon: Yes, it is the same object and no, it's not a double-registered observer - those were my initial thoughts, but creating a contrived example (where I can be sure that these two possibilities can be discounted) leads to the same results.

Comment: As an aside, you should refer to [Code Naming Basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingIvarsAndTypes.html) for naming conventions. Classes should start with uppercase letters. Properties with lowercase letters.

Comment: @Rob: Agreed - and +1 for that doc. Our team is mostly C++, however, and we have historical naming conventions which we're required to follow :-/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4451861/receiving-2-kvo-notifications-for-a-single-kvc-change
Here's why

Comment: @FernandoMazzon: Thanks, that's exactly what I was after. I've voted to close this as a dupe, please do the same if you're so inclined ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the docs. If you want manual, you have to override that:

> Manual Change Notification
>
> Manual change notification provides more granular control over how and
>   when notifications are sent to observers. This can be useful to help
>   minimize triggering notifications that are unnecessary, or to group a
>   number of changes into a single notification.
>
> A class that implements manual notification must override the NSObject
>   implementation of automaticallyNotifiesObserversForKey:. It is
>   possible to use both automatic and manual observer notifications in
>   the same class. For properties that perform manual notification, the
>   subclass implementation of automaticallyNotifiesObserversForKey:
>   should return NO. A subclass implementation should invoke super for
>   any unrecognized keys. The example in Listing 2 enables manual
>   notification for the openingBalance property allowing the superclass
>   to determine the notification for all other keys.

Comment: There is a great post on that matter http://petersteinberger.com/blog/2012/dont-call-willchangevalueforkey/